# str.replace not appearing to function properly when target string is contained in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my program I have a section of code that looks in one of my computer's directories for pickle files and puts their names in a list using a list comprehension. After this I am attempting to remove the ".pickle" file extension from each of the file names in the list, for reasons unnecessary to explain here. However, after iterating through the list and redefining each element as what it would be when passed into the str.replace built-in function and replacing the ".pickle" string with "", the names in the list do not appear to have changed. Here is my code:

```
import os
file_names = [file for file in os.listdir("C:/~~/dir") if file.endswith(".pickle")]
for each in file_names:
    each = each.replace(".pickle","")
```

The one pickle file that I'm using in the early stage of my program's development is the only in the directory.
The program has thrown no errors.
The name of the file itself is called "debugger.pickle" and when printing the "file_names" list it prints

```
['debugger.pickle']
```

instead of just

```
['debugger']
```

which is my desired result.

Comment: Setting a variable to a list element and then reassigning the variable doesn't modify the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`each = each.replace(".pickle","")` creates a new string and binds it to the name `each`. This has no effect on the original string object in `file_names`.

If the `.replace` method mutated its string in-place then

```
for each in file_names:
    each.replace(".pickle","")
```

would work, but that code won't actually do what you want because Python strings are immutable.

So you need to save the pruned strings, the simple way to do that is with a list comprehension:

```
file_names = [each.replace(".pickle","") for each in file_names]
```

Note that this replaces the original `file_names` list object with a new object. If you'd like to instead modify the original `file_names` object you can do

```
file_names[:] = [each.replace(".pickle","") for each in file_names]
```

That's slightly less efficient (and slower), but it can be useful if you have other objects referring to the original `file_names` object.

Comment: This answer provides a resolution to the issue of `file_names` not being altered but gives a misleading reason. It is not because "strings are immutable" - presumably the OP knows this since they are attempting to re-assign `each` in the loop. The mistake is that OP thinks `each` in each iteration is a reference to the member in `file_names` when it is actually just the value during each iteration.

Comment: @TheCardCheat: I agree that my original explanation could be misleading, so I've modified my answer. Hopefully, it's less misleading now, but if you have any suggestions please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can't replace items inline; try using map or a list comprehension to recreate the list:

```
import glob
import os

original_files = glob.glob(r'C:/foo/blah/*.pickle')
files = [os.path.basename(os.path.splitext(i)[0]) for i in original_files]
```

You can also combine it:

```
files = [os.path.basename(os.path.splitext(i)[0]) for i in glob.iglob(r'C:/foo/*.pickle')]
```